# Почему messages.send отправляется не более 20 сообщений ДРУЗЬЯМ?

Tags: vkontakte-api

Автоматическая рассылка одинакового сообщения друзьям пользователя, владельца токена.
После успешной отправки 20 сообщений выдает ошибку 7 Permission to perform this action is denied
При этом этим же пользователям с этого же аккаунта в vk.com это же сообщение уходит нормально.
Перегенерировал токен - не помогает.
Можете подсказать, что происходит?

Comment: Скорее всего, из-за рассылки спама выскакивает капча, которую вы игнорируете

Comment: Более того, есть ограничение на количество запросв в секунду. [Об ограничениях в документации](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests?f=3.%20%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: 1. Нет, капча имеет другой код ошибки и про нее написано в ответе
2. Сообщения отправляются с рандомной задержкой 10-20 секунд
3. Изменение текста сообщения проблему не решает
В тоже время со страницы в контакте это же сообщение этим же людям уходит нормально